# Uploaded content not showing in django 1.4

Tags: upload, django-1.4

I've recently updated a platform I'm working on to django 1.4. Since I've updated it, all the access to user uploaded content returns a HTTP 302 (Redirect) code, resulting in images now loading or content not reachable. I don't know where to search, since we haven't modified any code in the platform, apart from the `manage.py` file.

The URL generated to access the files is OK, so I don't understand why django returns a 302 code.

Any clues? I'm a bit lost with this. The user uploaded content worked perfectly fine before the update to 1.4.

You can find the curent code in http://github.com/cidadania/e-cidadania

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. The new i18n URLs of django 1.4 were messing everyting up, apart from the fact the I had the uploads directory hardcoded in the url.py file, I replaced it by "settings.MEDIA_ROOT" and problem solved